# triple booting on ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, software-recommendation, system-installation, software-installation

I have Windows 8, Windows 7 and Ubuntu x86 installed on my PC.

When I boot, GRUB2 comes up so I can boot.

I want to uninstall Windows 8 but keep Windows 7. How would I do this without breaking my system?

*EDIT:* I use the Windows 8 bootloader to boot Windows 7.

Comment: Actally i have to choose windows 8 loader to dual boot between Windows 8 and 7. So i want to know what will happen if i uninstall windows 8 and dual boot for Ubuntu and Windows 7

Comment: nothing really, just choose the windows 7 option at boot

Answer (score 0):

If this is dealing with the grub bootloader, then just delete the partition that windows 8 is on and use an ubuntu livecd and run "sudo update-grub /dev/[what is the name of the disk, something like sda probably] to remove the windows 8 boot entry